# Page break for new page using fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I want to create second page using fpdf.The code is given below.In the code from the specified area i want to start new page.Here the pdf class is extends from fpdf.

```
class PDF extends FPDF
 {

function header{
$this->Ln(20);
     $this->SetFont('Times','',10);
     $this->Cell(0,10,'Kondotty');
     $this->Ln(10);
     $this->SetFont('Times','',10);
     $this->Cell(80,0,'07/10/2014');


    $this->Cell(60,0,'Seal');
    $this->Cell(0,0,'Head of Institution');


//END FIRST PAGE

// STARTING SECOND PAGE




    $this->Ln(10);

    $this->Cell(27);
     $this->Cell(0,10,'Her conduct and character were found ...................................... during that period.');

     $this->Ln(20);
     $this->SetFont('Times','',10);
     $this->Cell(0,10,'Kondotty');
     $this->Ln(10);
     $this->SetFont('Times','',10);
     $this->Cell(80,0,'07/10/2014');
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

For example:

I declare `$i = 0;` at the beginning of my PDF and for every line I add in my foreach I count `$i` like `$i++`.
If you want a pagebreak after `x` lines for example you can just say:

```
if($i%30==0 && $i!=0) {
   $this->addPage();
}
```

And a function to add a new page:

```
private function addPage()
{
   $this->page = $this->pdf->newPage('A4');
```

I hope this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: $this->pdf->newPage('A4'); in this pdf-> refer to what?

Comment: i mean the word pdf is a object?

Comment: Yes, in my case it's $this->pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();